# My google action is taking time and the latency is coming to about 10seconds.How to handle the latency issue?

Tags: actions-on-google

I am doing some video processing, getting a live stream URL, and sending the response, which is taking the time and the latency is coming to about 10seconds. How to handle it.

Below is my action Execute code.

```
@NotNull
@Override
public ExecuteResponse onExecute(@NotNull ExecuteRequest executeRequest, @Nullable Map<?, ?> map) {
    ExecuteResponse.Payload payload = new ExecuteResponse.Payload();

    String streamUrl = getstreamurl();
    System.out.println("#######Url" + streamUrl);

    payload.setCommands(
        new ExecuteResponse.Payload.Commands[] {
        new ExecuteResponse.Payload.Commands(
        new String[] {"5e0f5d1820a57b00113d7a7c"},
        "SUCCESS",
        new HashMap<String, Object>() {
            {
                put("cameraStreamAccessUrl", streamUrl);
            }
        },
        null,
        null)
    });
    return new ExecuteResponse(executeRequest.getRequestId(), payload);
}
```

Issue:

Now in my case, after it recognizes the command (typed or spoken) google assistance is not waiting for the response from **getstreamurl()** function call after 3-5 seconds its automatically sending response "looks like the stream not found", **getstreamurl()** function call is taking the time and the latency is coming to about 10 seconds.
**How to handle the latency issue**.

Comment: Is there any way for you to preload the stream in a step before? If it takes very long possible you can initiate the stream loading asynchronously in one conversation step. Then if on the next step it's still not ready, you can mention the stream is not ready yet, please try again.

Comment: Another possibility is that you create an [interactive canvas](https://developers.google.com/assistant/interactivecanvas) action if it supports the platforms you are targeting as it supports asynchronous tasks much better.